# Use of math mode with SIstyle

Tags: math-mode, units

When using the `SIstyle` package, I noticed that numbers inside `\SI{}{}` and `\num{}` appear in a slightly different style than inside `$$`.

- Do the `\SI{}{}` and `\num{}` commands come with math mode already?
- Should I place math mode around this? E.g. `$\SI{}{}$` and `$\num{}$`.

Comment: Answers to your questions are on p. 4 of the `sistyle` user guide: "The numbers and units are set inside a math environment with an upright font. When the `\SI` command is used in normal text or inside inline maths, it follows the surrounding fonts. Display maths on the other hand will follow the active math fonts." Just in case you're not aware of this, the `sistyle` package ceased development and maintenance (other than simple bug fixes) several years ago. You may want to switch to using the `siunitx` package instead.

Comment: I looked at the documentation for `siunitx`, but could not find many of the units I need (e.g. "Mach", "ton", "pound", "light year", "liter", "inch", "Light year"), so I thought perhaps `sistyle` would be better.

Comment: @Village: `siunitx` is quite strict with what units are included by defaults (almost exclusively "proper" SI units). Litres/liters are included as `\litre` (yielding `l`) and `\liter` (yielding `L`), tons are `\tonne`. The other units can be defined really easily using  `\DeclareSIUnit\mach{Ma}`, `\DeclareSIUnit\pound{lbs}`, `\DeclareSIUnit\inch{in}`, and `\DeclareSIUnit\lightyear{ly}`. I would definitely recommend going with `siunitx`, especially for the great number printing and tabular alignment features.

Comment: Check out section 4.5 of the `siunitx` manual and the `\DeclareSIUnit` command for guidance on creating one's own (highly non-SI!) units. E.g., `\DeclareSIUnit\lightyear{ly}` should work for you, right? `siunitx` recognizes `\tonne`, by the way (though not `\ton`).

Comment: 'tonne' is a metric unit and is in the BIPM docs (http://www.bipm.org/en/si/si_brochure/chapter4/table6.html). 'ton' is the name for two imperial units: the long ton (2240 lb) and the short ton (2000 lb).

Comment: Can I adjust my question to be about the `siunitx` package? When using `situnitx`, should I put use `$\SI{}{}$` and `$\num{}$` or just allow the package to choose how it likes to display the text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SIstyle` follows the local environment font definition. If your text and math fonts (`mathrm`) are different, it will give different output.

I am not doing any further development work (just maintenace) on `SIstyle` and everthing has moved over to `siunitx` where Joseph Wright is doing a fantastic job. I would recommend to change to `siunitx`

Comment: Okay, I will switch to `siunitx`.